# Angular: Please turn on my light so I can see

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to toggle my 2 on & off images when I click on my lightbulb. Sometimes it seems to work and other times it does not. I cant get the ng-click to work at all unless I use ng-repeat and at least two images. How do I best accomplish toggling the images for 1 lightbulb? Is there any way to synchronize the checkbox so that when it is checked the light goes on and when it is off the light goes off? (I am new to javascript)Here's the fiddle:
[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gogirl/7857c/)

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  lightbulb is {{state}}     <input type="checkbox" ng-model=
  "state" ng-true-value="on" ng-false-value="off"> 

    <div ng-repeat="image in images"> 
        <a ng-click="toggleImage(image)">
            <img  ng-src="{{image.imgUrl}}" />                                 
        </a>

    </div>
</div>
```

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
//$scope.checkboxState = "off";
//$scope.resetUrl = 'http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif';
$scope.state = "on";
$scope.onUrl = 'http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif';
$scope.offUrl = 'http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif';
$scope.images = [
    {imgUrl: 'http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulboff.gif'},
    {imgUrl: 'http://www.w3schools.com/js/pic_bulbon.gif'},
];

$scope.toggleImage = function (image) {
    if (image === $scope.offUrl) {

        image.imgUrl = $scope.onUrl;
    } else {

        image.imgUrl = $scope.offUrl; 

    }
};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to toggle something is to store the state in your scope and then render based on that. Right now you have a lot of extraneous code that could be eliminated. I would restructure your code to something like:

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.onUrl = "pic_bulbon.gif";
    $scope.offUrl = "pic_bulboff.gif";
    $scope.isBulbOn = false;
    $scope.bulbText = function() { return $scope.isBulbOn ? "on" : "off"; };
    $scope.bulbUrl = function() { 
        return $scope.isBulbOn ? $scope.onUrl : $scope.offUrl; 
    };
}
```

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
        lightbulb is {{ bulbText() }}
        <input type="checkbox" ng-model="isBulbOn">

        <a ng-click="isBulbOn = !isBulbOn">
            <img ng-src="{{ bulbUrl() }}" />
        </a>
    </div>
</body>
```

You can check out the Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/UYaLJ/

Comment: What a turn on: Clean code and beautiful job on the refactoring Justin. It is exactly what I had in mind but could not express. Is it correct to assume that I could not use this style were I changing traffic lights that have 3 states rather than two? Would I then have to use some kind of switch statement?

Comment: Just for js newbies like me: The ng-click returns a bool that is bound to the ng-model bool. To toggle a bool: one and two equivalent
1.bool = bool ? false : true;
2.bool = !bool; 
To convert string to boolean:: one and two equivalent and three misleading so Justin variable names was a help.
1. var boolVal = (string === "true");
2. var boolVal = (string ==="true") ? true : false;
3.less readable: string = (string=="true") ? true : false;

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with the `if`condition. The ng-repeat works on the JSON object. Hence, the function parameter 'image' is an object. The correct `if` statement is as follows:

```
if (image.imgUrl === $scope.offUrl) {
```

I have updated the fiddle. URL is:http://jsfiddle.net/7857c/1/